# Como hago para que me devuelva el array?

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for

Lo que tengo que hacer es que si el valor que tenga caracteres (Un número entero) coincide con el largo de uno de los string que están dentro de un arreglo (parámetro "strings"), que lo devuelva en un nuevo arreglo.

Ya no se como solucionarlo

```js
function mismaCantidadCaracteres(strings, caracteres) {
  let lista = [];
  for (let x = 0; x <= strings.length; x++) {
    if (strings[x].length === caracteres) {
      lista.push(strings[x]);
    }
    return lista;
  }
}

//Ejemplo de uso de la función
console.log(mismaCantidadCaracteres(['hi', 'hello', 'ni hao', 'guten tag'], 2));
```

Quien pueda ayudarme le agradecería mucho

Answer (score 2):

Estabas muy cerca de la solucion, solo necesitabas sacar el `return` del bucle y cambiar la comparacion a `<`.  Quedaria asi:

```js
function mismaCantidadCaracteres(strings, caracteres){
 let lista = [];
 for(let x=0;x<strings.length;x++){
    if(strings[x].length === caracteres){
        lista.push(strings[x]);
    }    
 }
 return lista;
}


console.log(mismaCantidadCaracteres(['hi', 'hello', 'ni hao', 'guten tag'], 2))
```